# passing value from one page to another

Tags: silverlight

i m new developer to mobile apps and working on silverlight.

i want to knw how to pass value from textbox on one page to textbox on another page in mobile windows apps not in web apps using silverlight in c#.

Comment: do you use MVVM Pattern? or how to navigate to other pages?

Answer (score 0):

So many options for this one:

- Add variables to your app class
- Global variable anywhere in the app (yuk)
- Use a shared ViewModel if you are following the MVVM pattern
- Store in App.Resource settings (these are easily bound to)
- There is a shared app data store specifically  for binding, but I can't remember what it is called or if it is in the mobile version (anybody?).

What are you doing with this value that is shared between to pages? The usage determines where/how it should be stored.